# Nuxt.js Role Based Rendering on Server

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

I have two roles in my database. First one is Admin and second one is normal User. I have a page that shows users table to both Admin and normal User. However, for Admin I want to show a button that creates new user with email and password. I do not want to show this button to normal User. I want it to be done on server and I do not want to set isAdmin parameter to vuex states. Because if I set it to vuex state then I can easily change the data using vue devtools... Is there any solution to render conditionally. Not like this:

```
<template>   <div>
     <b-table striped hover :items="getUserList"></b-table>
     <b-button v-if="isAdmin" variant="primary" size="lg" to="/add_user">+</b-button>   </div> </template>

<script> import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex"; import axios from "axios";

export default {   middleware: 'authorize-user',   methods: {
    async getUserList() {
      try {
        let res = await axios.post("/api/users");
        if (res && res.data) {
          return res.data.users ? res.data.users : [];
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("user fetch failed");
      }
    }   },   computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['isAdmin'])   } } </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any js code on client can be altered and accessed. So your concern isn`t a valid one. You always should check permission on server. So in that case even if they change isAdmin on client and make button appear - it still wont do anything on click.

Comment: Yes I also check it on server side. If button appears for normal user using some attack, user still can not add user because he is not admin and I have a validation on server side also. However, I do not want to show normal user to this button. I do not want it to control using my vuex store. I want it to be rendered from server.

Comment: @user3657011 normal user wont see this button. Only one who will see it will be the one who try to hack and it doesnt matter because server check. You are trying to solve problem that dont make much sense. And every page could be accessed within app when going through link, so it should be rendered on client